# Как изменить центр координат в JS

Tags: javascript

Есть некий объект .box h=100px w=100px
Хочу вывести координаты курсора. Отчет координат по-умолчанию идет из верхнего левого угла, а нужно, чтобы отчет координат шел из центра объекта .box. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать.

Comment: Нарисуйте в этом квадрате другой квадрат 50х50рх, спозиционируйте в правый нижний угол и начинайте отсчет координат от него)

Comment: Вычтите из обоих координат 50. Получится то что вам нужно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простой вариант который я смог придумать.

Чтобы узнать координаты курсора сы вешас на окно евент `mousemove` который будет срабатывать каждый раз когда мы будет двинать курсор.
С помощью событья `e` и функций `clientX` мы узнаём текущий координаты на главной страницы, чтобы отчет координат шёл из центра нашего блока мы должны  вычитать позицию блока и половину его размера (цирина по ОСИ x и высоту по ОСИ y)

```js
const box = document.querySelector('.box');

window.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  let leftPos = e.clientX - box.offsetLeft - box.offsetWidth / 2;
  let topPos = e.clientY - box.offsetTop - box.offsetHeight / 2;
  console.log('x:' + leftPos, 'y:' + topPos);
})
```

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: royalblue;
}

.box:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: darkred;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает